# macOS Remote Push Notifications Not Showing Alert Banner

Tags: swift, macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to enable Push Notifications for my macOS application. Everything seems to be working. I'm able to get the device token. Send the notification without errors. Except there is no alert that shows up on my Mac.

I added the following code to see if my application was receiving it or not.

```
func application(_ application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : Any]) {
    print(userInfo)
}
```

And after I send a notification I see the following in the console.

```
["aps": {
    alert = "Alert - Hello World";
    sound = "ping.aiff";
}]
```

So it looks like it's getting to the device ok, just not showing the alert.

I have tested the exact same setup on iOS and it's working fine and showing the alert there. So I must be missing something specifically on macOS.

I have tried the following things to fix this:

1. Tested with application closed and open (didn't work either time)
2. Ensured that notifications are enabled for application in System Preferences

[image: System Preferences Image]

3. If I create a local notification manually in code, it works perfectly, and the notification banner appears
4. I can not test it on older versions of macOS because the push notification API I'm using was just released in macOS Mojave
5. I have also tried to create another test project, and the same problem happened
6. I have ensured that Do Not Disturb is turned off, and have also checked in the notification center for the notification, but it does not display there either.

How can I get it to show the banner and play the sound on macOS?

Comment: I know you already specified this in your answer, but I didn't see when I came through so I think this might help some people to see this picture. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cC1S.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cC1S.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS the following code works fine:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { granted, _ in
    guard granted else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

For macOS I changed that code to be:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { granted, _ in
    guard granted else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Turns out the line `NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` is incorrect. On macOS you have to pass in the same options you provided into this call.

Changing that line to the following worked.

```
NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
```

What I find strange is that in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428476-registerforremotenotifications) it says that method is deprecated, and that we should use `registerForRemoteNotifications()` instead. Which makes me think there is some type of bug with `registerForRemoteNotifications()` where the notifications are not appearing correctly.

One other thing to mention. It did take a little bit of time (couple minutes), and a few notifications sent, for them to actually appear after making that change. Not sure if it was just due to slow internet connection or what. But now they are appearing very quickly after being sent.

---

**Edit**

Apple has informed me that this is fixed in macOS 10.14.4. I have not been able to upgrade to the best and test it yet tho. So I can not confirm at this point. I will update this when I get a chance to test on macOS 10.14.4.

Comment: > Which makes me think there is some type of bug with registerForRemoteNotifications() where the notifications are not appearing correctly.  **I agree**

Comment: @erkanyildiz Are you experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Yes. Calling `requestAuthorization` on `UNUserNotificationCenter` and then calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` does not work. Even though the app appears in macOS Notifications pref pane with `Badges, Sounds, Banners` options, notifications are not displayed. Only when I use `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method it works.

Answer (score -1):

Clarifying, this is macOS, and NSApp is just NSApplication.shared

Actually I have to amend my answer because I did have some inconsistent results, so right now, I do have

```
if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { [weak self] (success, error) in
        if let error = error {
        // LOG
        } else {
            NSApp.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .badge, .sound])
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories(varWithMyCategories)
        }
    }
} else {
    NSApp.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: NSApp is NSapplication.shared: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapp

Comment: and the docs for NSApp.registerForRemoteNotifications() is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/2967172-registerforremotenotifications?language=objc

Comment: You should normally provide working code. Just saying `NSApp` won't compile. Also `NSApp.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .badge, .sound])` isn't even a method in macOS. `registerForRemoteNotifications` doesn't accept any parameters in macOS. Did you read my answer? Is there a problem with my answer? According to the bug I filed with Apple this was fixed in macOS 10.14.4. I haven't had time to upgrade and test it yet tho.

Comment: NSApp does compile. Its in macOS since 10.0: "macOS 10.0+" `registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .badge, .sound])` is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428476-registerforremotenotifications  and it's available since macOS 10.7 and was deprecated in 10.14 Mojave - please lookup the Mac documentation before commenting.

Comment: Fine. You still didn’t answer either of my questions. And I’m not sure why you are suggesting to use deprecated methods...

Comment: it's deprecated but it does work in 10.14.3. I was using first only the old NSUserNotification methods (as my app does support 10.11 and later) but added option 10.14 because of the categories support. Sorry if I didn't understood the question.

Comment: I'm still really curious why this answer is even necessary. According to Apple this is a bug that was resolved in 10.14.4. See my answer above. I'm not sure what this answer adds to this thread.

Comment: well 10.14.4 seems great but it's not out yet. And even after it's out, not everyone will update right away (this will in a prod release sometime around Feb 25/2019). So while I am happy that Apple is fixing the bug, it really won't help users with any 10.14.[0-3] versions. And this is the bug is really fixed in 10.14.4. But yeah, for future use, no need to use the deprecated method, only `NSApp. NSApp.registerForRemoteNotifications()`.

Comment: How do you know it'll be out in a prod release sometime around 2/25/19? This answer still doesn't add any value in my opinion. I said that changing the line to `NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .sound, .badge])` worked. How does your answer add value beyond that?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding here. I do have the same problem but I DO need to ship this week, not you. And I was just explaining that `NSApp` is indeed part of the Cocoa framework, no need to use `NSApplication.shared`. - just a clarification, sorry about it.