# registerForRemoteNotifications not working at all in Big Sur?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, macos-big-sur

I am working on a macOS app that involves remote notifications. In my app delegate `appDidFinishLaunching`, I simply call

```
NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

I then get one of two callbacks in the app delegate, either `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` or `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`. This has worked fine forever in previous versions.

In Big Sur, this does not seem to work at all. I call the registerForRemoteNotifications, but I never get either callback called.

My hypothesis was that this is because of the new app lifecycle (which is where I originally tried this out). I built a small test app with AppKit app delegate lifecycle. It is equally broken there.

What gives? Why cannot I register for remote notifications in Big Sur?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm in the same situation. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called with a Production profile but not with a Development profile.

Comment: No solution yet that I know of. Wrote a blog post about it: https://jaanus.com/big-sur-remote-notifications/ Some sources say that it is fixed in Big Sur 11.2, but I am finding it still not working.

Comment: This answer worked for me eventually https://stackoverflow.com/a/53142778/2112116. Essentially using `NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .sound, .badge])` instead of  `NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`. Apparently a macOS bug that hasn't been resolved even in Big Sur 11.2.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only broken in the development environment. It was always working as expected in production environment, but it was of course difficult to develop and test with this.

This was fixed in one of the minor versions of Big Sur. I am now using 11.5.1 and it is working now as expected in all environments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed in 11.3 Beta (20E5186d).

Comment: You had better write this as a comment.

Comment: The answer seems fine, if it is really fixed  I can’t test with the beta myself, I’ll test once the final version is released.

Comment: just installed 11.3.1 - still not working